# execute .sh script from cygwin on windows task scheduler

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to execute this .sh script on cygwin on windows machine  but  receiving this error.

this is the script:

```
fetchReviewImages.sh
====================

#!/bin/bash
mysql -u root -pjavahot -B -e "SELECT camera_name, id FROM inteliviz.cameras;" --skip-column-names | while read CAM_NAME CAM_ID
do 
    /xampp/htdocs/getReviewImages.py $CAM_ID
done

Cygwin error:
===============
$  C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -l -c "C:/xampp/htdocs/fetchReviewImages.sh"
C:/xampp/htdocs/fetchReviewImages.sh: line 3: mysql: command not found
```

Comment: `mysql: command not found` <-- this is your problem...

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql.sock' (2)